# How do I open an image from an url in python 3.6?

Tags: python, image, url, python-3.6

Hi guys I want to know how to open an image from an image url.
I want it to open just like how you open something that is on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("https://url/img.jpg") #or file:///
```